# Adding links to a menu without re-selecting the menu each time

Tags: 8, navigation

I am adding links to a (SuperFish) menu in Drupal 8. Each time I add a link it returns me to the list of menus (admin/structure/menu).

How can I add menu links without having to re-select the menu each time?

I think that newly created menus operate the way I want, but I want to add links to an existing menu.

So far my best method is to store the URL for adding a menu item in the clipboard.

> admin/structure/menu/manage/main-ejn-menu/add

Answer (score 0):

So do you want it to go add to the add menu item screen after creating one? What is in the url does it have something like ?destination=/admin/structure/menu

You could change that to

```
admin/structure/menu/manage/main-ejn-menu/add?destination=admin/structure/menu/manage/main-ejn-menu/add
```

Comment: That works once.  I can add two menu items and then I am in edit mode for the second item.